# How to map port from API Gateway to AWS Cloud Map?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudmap

I am using HTTP API type in AWS API Gateway. How to map port from AWS API Gateway to AWS Cloud Map?

Is this available in some AWS API Gateway setting?

Answer (score 2):

I found that port mapping is not defined in API Gateway, but in ECS Service related with Cloud Map. Therefore, we should define the mapping in ECS service definition.